# Scribe Insight: Generate a new csv file each time

Tags: export-to-csv, data-migration, scribe-workbench

I'm looking for a way to create a new csv file each time the job is triggered. Every time the job is triggered it needs to create a new file like DataProject"projectnumber".csv in a certain folder (always the same folder)

But I cannot found the way to accomplish this.
Currently my approach is to store everything in a sql table and create the file from there but I'm actually looking for a way to do it from Scribe.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this can be done in Scribe Insight.

I've done something similar where I've used Scribe to create the file, and then some VBScript to rename it.

Mike

Comment: That sound interesting. So, Scribe creates the file and VBScript rename it, each time?
Can this work if the path it in a Shared Folder in the network?

Comment: "Scribe creates the file and VBScript rename it, each time" - Yes  

"Can this work if the path it in a Shared Folder in the network" - Yes